# Importing Custom JS file to AngularJS 4 which is built on JQuery

Tags: jquery, angular, angular-cli

I am facing a problem while importing a customer Javascript file which is built on top of jQuery in to Angular4 project.

I installed jQuery using npm and import it in to component. Added jquery.js file in scripts of angular-cli.json file. After this, I was able to put some code in my component which is running on jQuery and it worked fine. Then I added my custom js file in assets folder and imported in component file(did not work), then added in index.html file(this approach worked and I was able to access normal method, if I dont have any jquery specific code). But getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" error while trying to call a method written on external custom js file since jquery's document.ready.

What is the best approach to accomplish this.

my javascript file look like this.

```
    var abc;
    var cde;

    $.document.ready(function(){

      iniializePage()
     });

    function iniializePage(){
     var test = $("#ffff").val();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

just declare it in your component at top  like

declare var $: any;

than use it anywhere